# Projecting a stretched grid to the unit disk?

Tags: geometry, surfaces, curves, projective-geometry, spherical-geometry

What is happening mathematically in this image? How does one represent the grid on the ball mathematically?

I've observed that there seem to be four points at infinity in which grid lines meet. I would also say I think this is in the scope of spherical geometry.

> Q: If you projected the grid on the transparent ball down onto a disk, would this projection be an isometry? Would the transformation be conformal?

I don't think it would be an isometry but I think it could be conformal.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law

Comment: Is that a glass ball, or is it a reflective ball?

Comment: It’s a glass ball

Comment: Oh, well. Then the first step really *is* Snell's Law, combined with everything you learn about raytracing in just about any graphics book. If it were a reflective sphere, then the "curvy" black lines might (if you had a camera with a really long focal length) actually be circle-arcs; once you throw in the snell-refraction law, I pretty much doubt it.

Comment: Just a hunch... If the ball is a reflective hyperboloid of 1 sheet then the lines imaged on far-off /high $f$ camera would be circles.

Comment: @Ultradark Does the thick lens ball have a hemisphere or segment of sphere for its profile?

Comment: How can it be conformal if the (right) angles aren't being preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a ball lens. Here is some Mathematica code that **symbolically** performs the raytracing using [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law):

```
p0y = 0;
u0x = 1;
radius = 1;
Clear[p0x, u0y, index, wall]

p0 = {p0x, p0y};
u0 = {u0x, u0y};

p1 = ((p0 + 
      t*u0) /. (Solve[Norm[p0 + t*u0]^2 == radius^2, t] // First // 
      Simplify)) // Simplify;(*intersection with ball surface*)

u0normal = (u0.p1)*p1;
u0perp = u0 - u0normal;
u1 = (u0normal + u0perp/index) // 
  Simplify;(*Snell's law*)
p2 = ((p1 + 
      t*u1) /. (Solve[Norm[p1 + t*u1]^2 == radius^2, t] // Last // 
      Simplify)) // Simplify;(*intersection with ball surface*)

u1normal = (u1.p2)*p2;
u1perp = u1 - u1normal;
u2 = (u1normal + u1perp*index) // 
  Simplify;(*Snell's law*)
p3 = ((p2 + 
      t*u2) /. (Solve[(p2 + t*u2).{1, 0} == wall, t] // First // 
      Simplify)) // 
  Simplify;(*intersection with wall, this may not be a valid solution \
since the ray exiting the ball may point away from the wall*)

p4 = ((p0 + t*u0) /. (Solve[(p0 + t*u0).{1, 0} == wall, t] // First //
       Simplify)) // Simplify;(*intersection with wall*)

Manipulate[
 Evaluate@Graphics[{
    InfiniteLine[{wall, 0}, {0, 1}],
    HalfLine[p2, u2],
    Line[{p0, p1, p2}],
    Circle[{0, 0}, radius],
    Dotted,
    HalfLine[p1, u0]
    }, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
 ,
 {{p0x, -4, "distance from eye to ball center"}, -4, -1},
 {{u0y, 0.25, "slope of line of sight"}, -2, 2},
 {{index, 20, "relative refractive index of ball"}, 0, 1000},
 {{wall, 2, "distance from ball center to wall"}, 1, 10}
 ]
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Note that the exiting ray may point *away* from the wall behind the ball. Let $d_1$ be the distance from the eye to the ball center and $d_2$ be the distance from the ball center to the wall behind it. Then, as the refractive index approaches infinity, the *actual* viewing angle (relative to the center of your field of vision when looking at the center of the ball) as a function of the apparent viewing angle $a$ is

```
(*f returns the actual angle as a function of apparent angle*)
f[a_] = ArcTan[
    Last[Limit[p3, index -> Infinity]]/(-p0x + wall) /. {u0y -> 
       u0x*Tan[a]}] // FullSimplify;
f[a] /. {p0x -> -Subscript[d, 1], wall -> Subscript[d, 2]} // 
  Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

$$\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(d_1+d_2\right) \cot (a) \left(-2 d_1 \sqrt{\sec ^2(a)-d_1^2 \tan ^2(a)}-\csc ^2(a)+2 d_1^2\right)}{-d_2 \csc ^2(a)+d_1 \left(2 d_2 \cot ^2(a) \sqrt{\sec ^2(a)-d_1^2 \tan ^2(a)}-\csc ^2(a)\right)+2 d_1^2 d_2}\right)$$

where defined.